# What is difference between webpack 1 and webpack 2?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

> We are going to migrate from Webpack1 to Webpack2. but I want to know
>   the basic difference between these two. How and Why the execution of webpack
>   2 is faster the webpack1?

Answer (score 1):

You can see what was changed [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) and see the [changelog](https://webpack.github.io/docs/changelog.html) of v1.
They recommend v2, because a lot of progress was made on performance.

I would recommend v3, since it has a lot of more features that have a great impact of build time and file sizes.

See Larkin's [post about V3 official release](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-3-official-release-15fd2dd8f07b)

**Edit**

Since you're asking the real impact, I can't give you the answer, but it was a webpack's internal rework.

Beware that changing to v2/v3 has a lot of modifications on the configuration file.

But don't let those scary modifications prevent you from upgrading it. It's worth.

Answer (score 1):

There are some API changes in webpack 2. Here is a migration guide from webpack 1 to webpack 2: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

However, I don't really know if the second version is faster than the first (I didn't notice any difference in a build performance).